# Why does my console.log statement stop working using webpack and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I setup a new rails app using webpack.
The default console.log shows up fine when I run the app.

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
// To reference this file, add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> to the appropriate
// layout file, like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
```

Now if I simply add file here:

```
/app/javascript/packs/application.scss
```

And I restart the rails s, the console.log disappears.

Is there some kind of a conflict?

So to summarize, the console.log message works in my new rails app with --wepack.  The moment I do this:

1. add application.scss in the /app/javascript/packs folder
2. Reference the application.scss in my layout

The console.log message stops working.  I start/stop the rails s and still no console.log message.

Comment: Did you add `javascript_pack_tag 'application'` in your layout ?

Comment: Yes, the console.log displays.  When I add an application.scss and stylesheet_pack_tag in my layout then it is gone for some reason.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a problem that I encountered today.

What worked for me as to create a subfolder inside `app/javascript/packs` folder.

My directory now looks like this:

- `app/javascript/packs/stylesheets/application.scss`
- `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

In my `application.haml`

- `= javascript_pack_tag 'application'`
- `= stylesheet_pack_tag 'stylesheets/application'`

If I put the `application.scss` in the same directory as `application.js` the `console.log()` stops working as you suggest.

My guess is that since both are named `application`, webpacker confuses on which file must be loaded on `javascript_pack_tag` and `stylesheet_pack_tag`.

That is why moving it on a different directory will solve the problem in my case.

Comment: THANKYOU.  I lost a day because of this application.scss problem.  I would never have figured it out.  I wonder which blog I followed!